# Joining list of data.frames from map() call

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tidyverse

Is there a "tidyverse" way to join a list of data.frames (a la `full_join()`, but for >2 data.frames)? I have a list of data.frames as a result of a call to `map()`. I've used `Reduce()` to do something like this before, but would like to merge them as part of a pipeline - just haven't found an elegant way to do that. Toy example:

```
library(tidyverse)

## Function to make a data.frame with an ID column and a random variable column with mean = df_mean
make.df <- function(df_mean){
  data.frame(id = 1:50,
             x = rnorm(n = 50, mean = df_mean))
}

## What I'd love:
my.dfs <- map(c(5, 10, 15), make.df) #%>%
  # <<some magical function that will full_join() on a list of data frames?>>

## Gives me the result I want, but inelegant
my.dfs.joined <- full_join(my.dfs[[1]], my.dfs[[2]], by = 'id') %>%
  full_join(my.dfs[[3]], by = 'id')

## Kind of what I want, but I want to merge, not bind
my.dfs.bound <- map(c(5, 10, 15), make.df) %>%
  bind_cols()
```

Comment: `purrr::reduce` is a wrapper for `Reduce` with the parameters reversed so it pipes better.

Comment: Fantastic - I hadn't known about `purrr::reduce`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `Reduce`

```
set.seed(1453)
r1 <- map(c(5, 10, 15), make.df)  %>% 
           Reduce(function(...) full_join(..., by = "id"), .)
```

Or this can be done with `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
set.seed(1453)
r2 <- map(c(5, 10, 15), make.df)  %>%
             reduce(full_join, by = "id")

identical(r1, r2)
#[1] TRUE
```