# dplyr : how-to programmatically full_join dataframes contained in a list of lists?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyverse

### Context and data structure

I'll share with you a simplified version of my huge dataset. This simplified version fully respects the structure of my original dataset but contains less list elements, dataframes, variables and observations than the original one.

According to the most upvoted answer to the question : [How to make a great R reproducible example ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I share my dataset using the output of `dput(query1)` to give you something that can be immediately used in R by copy/paste the following code block in the R console :

```
       structure(list(plu = structure(list(year = structure(list(id = 1:3,
    station = 100:102, pluMean = c(0.509068994778059, 1.92866478959912,
    1.09517453602154), pluMax = c(0.0146962179957886, 0.802984389130343,
    2.48170762478472)), .Names = c("id", "station", "pluMean",
"pluMax"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), month = structure(list(
    id = 1:3, station = 100:102, pluMean = c(0.66493845927034,
    -1.3559338786041, 0.195600637750077), pluMax = c(0.503424623872161,
    0.234402501255681, -0.440264545434053)), .Names = c("id",
"station", "pluMean", "pluMax"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"),
    week = structure(list(id = 1:3, station = 100:102, pluMean = c(-0.608295829330578,
    -1.10256919591373, 1.74984007126193), pluMax = c(0.969668266601551,
    0.924426323739882, 3.47460867665884)), .Names = c("id", "station",
    "pluMean", "pluMax"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("year",
"month", "week")), tsa = structure(list(year = structure(list(
    id = 1:3, station = 100:102, tsaMean = c(-1.49060721773042,
    -0.684735418997484, 0.0586655881113975), tsaMax = c(0.25739838787582,
    0.957634817758648, 1.37198023881125)), .Names = c("id", "station",
"tsaMean", "tsaMax"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"),
    month = structure(list(id = 1:3, station = 100:102, tsaMean = c(-0.684668662999479,
    -1.28087846387974, -0.600175481941456), tsaMax = c(0.962916941685075,
    0.530773351897188, -0.217143593955998)), .Names = c("id",
    "station", "tsaMean", "tsaMax"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"),
    week = structure(list(id = 1:3, station = 100:102, tsaMean = c(0.376481732842365,
    0.370435880636005, -0.105354927593471), tsaMax = c(1.93833635147645,
    0.81176751708868, 0.744932493064975)), .Names = c("id", "station",
    "tsaMean", "tsaMax"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("year",
"month", "week"))), .Names = c("plu", "tsa"))
```

After executing this, if you execute `str(query1),` you'll get the structure of my example dataset as  :

```
    > str(query1)
List of 2
 $ plu:List of 3
  ..$ year :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ id     : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ station: int [1:3] 100 101 102
  .. ..$ pluMean: num [1:3] 0.509 1.929 1.095
  .. ..$ pluMax : num [1:3] 0.0147 0.803 2.4817
  ..$ month:'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ id     : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ station: int [1:3] 100 101 102
  .. ..$ pluMean: num [1:3] 0.665 -1.356 0.196
  .. ..$ pluMax : num [1:3] 0.503 0.234 -0.44
  ..$ week :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ id     : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ station: int [1:3] 100 101 102
  .. ..$ pluMean: num [1:3] -0.608 -1.103 1.75
  .. ..$ pluMax : num [1:3] 0.97 0.924 3.475
 $ tsa:List of 3
  ..$ year :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ id     : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ station: int [1:3] 100 101 102
  .. ..$ tsaMean: num [1:3] -1.4906 -0.6847 0.0587
  .. ..$ tsaMax : num [1:3] 0.257 0.958 1.372
  ..$ month:'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ id     : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ station: int [1:3] 100 101 102
  .. ..$ tsaMean: num [1:3] -0.685 -1.281 -0.6
  .. ..$ tsaMax : num [1:3] 0.963 0.531 -0.217
  ..$ week :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ id     : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ station: int [1:3] 100 101 102
  .. ..$ tsaMean: num [1:3] 0.376 0.37 -0.105
  .. ..$ tsaMax : num [1:3] 1.938 0.812 0.745
```

So how does it reads ? I have *big list* (`query1`) made of  2 *parameters* elements (`plu` & `tsa`), each of these 2 *parameters* elements being a list made of 3 elements (`year`, `month`, `week`), each of these 3 elements being a *timeInterval* dataframe made of the same 4 *variables* columns (`id`, `station`, `mean`, `max`) and exactly the same number of observations (`3`).

### What I want to achieve

I want to **programmatically** `full_join` by `id` & `station` all the *timeInterval* dataframes with the same name (`year`, `month`, `week`). This means that I should end up with a new list (`query1Changed`) containing 3 dataframes (`year`, `month`, `week`), each of them containing 5 columns (`id`, `station`, `pluMean`, `pluMax`, `tsaMean`, `tsaMax`) and 3 observations. Schematically, I need to arrange data as follows :

**do a full_join by station and id of :**

- df`query1$plu$year` with df `query1$tsa$year`
- df`query1$plu$month` with df `query1$tsa$month`
- df`query1$plu$week` with df `query1$tsa$week`

Or expressed with another representation :

- df`query1[[1]][[1]]` with df `query1[[2]][[1]]`
- df`query1[[1]][[2]]` with df `query1[[2]][[2]]`
- df`query1[[1]][[3]]` with df `query1[[2]][[3]]`

And expressed programmatically (n being the total number of elements of the big list) :

- df`query1[[i]][[1]]` with df `query1[[i+1]][[1]]`... with df `query1[[n]][[1]]`
- df`query1[[i]][[2]]` with df `query1[[i+1]][[2]]`... with df `query1[[n]][[2]]`
- df`query1[[i]][[3]]` with df `query1[[i+1]][[3]]`... with df `query1[[n]][[3]]`

I need to achieve this programmatically because in my real project I could encounter another *big list* with more than 2 *parameters* elements and more than 4 *variables* columns in each of their *timeIntervals* dataframes .

In my analysis, what will always remain the same is the fact that all the *parameters* elements of another *big list* will always have the same number of *timeIntervals* dataframes with the same names and each of these *timeIntervals* dataframes will always have the same number of observations and always share 2 columns with exactly the same name and same values (`id` & `station`)

### What i have succeeded

Executing the following piece of code :

```
> query1Changed <- do.call(function(...) mapply(bind_cols, ..., SIMPLIFY=F), args = query1)
```

arranges the data as expected. However this is not a neat solution since we end up with repeated column names (`id` & `station`)  :

```
> str(query1Changed)
List of 3
 $ year :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ id      : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ station : int [1:3] 100 101 102
  ..$ pluMean : num [1:3] 0.509 1.929 1.095
  ..$ pluMax  : num [1:3] 0.0147 0.803 2.4817
  ..$ id1     : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ station1: int [1:3] 100 101 102
  ..$ tsaMean : num [1:3] -1.4906 -0.6847 0.0587
  ..$ tsaMax  : num [1:3] 0.257 0.958 1.372
 $ month:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ id      : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ station : int [1:3] 100 101 102
  ..$ pluMean : num [1:3] 0.665 -1.356 0.196
  ..$ pluMax  : num [1:3] 0.503 0.234 -0.44
  ..$ id1     : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ station1: int [1:3] 100 101 102
  ..$ tsaMean : num [1:3] -0.685 -1.281 -0.6
  ..$ tsaMax  : num [1:3] 0.963 0.531 -0.217
 $ week :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ id      : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ station : int [1:3] 100 101 102
  ..$ pluMean : num [1:3] -0.608 -1.103 1.75
  ..$ pluMax  : num [1:3] 0.97 0.924 3.475
  ..$ id1     : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ station1: int [1:3] 100 101 102
  ..$ tsaMean : num [1:3] 0.376 0.37 -0.105
  ..$ tsaMax  : num [1:3] 1.938 0.812 0.745
```

We could add a second process to "clean" the data but this would not be the most efficient solution. So I don't want to use this workaround.

Next, I've tried doing the same using dplyr full_join but with no success. Executing the following code :

```
> query1Changed <- do.call(function(...) mapply(full_join(..., by = c("station", "id")), ..., SIMPLIFY=F), args = query1)
```

returns the following error :

```
Error in UseMethod("full_join") :
  no applicable method for 'full_join' applied to an object of class "list"
```

So, how should I write my full_join expression to make it run on the dataframes ?

or is there another way to perform my data transformation efficiently ?

## What I've found on the web that could help ?

I've found the related questions but I still can't figure out how to adapt their solutions to my problem.

**On stackoverflow** :
 - [Merging a data frame from a list of data frames [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229042/merging-a-data-frame-from-a-list-of-data-frames)
 - [Simultaneously merge multiple data.frames in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)
 - [Joining list of data.frames from map() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147372/joining-list-of-data-frames-from-map-call)
 - [Combining elements of list of lists by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500492/combining-elements-of-list-of-lists-by-index)

**On blogs :**
 - [Joining a List of Data Frames with purrr::reduce()](https://daranzolin.github.io/articles/2016-12/join-list-dataframes)

*Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope I've made the description of my problem clear.
I've started programming with R only 2 months ago so please be indulgent if the solution is obvious ;)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, thanks for posting a really great description of what your problem is and which requirements you need for your solution.

First, I'd use `purrr::map2` to create a function that takes two lists of data frames and joins them in parallel. That is, it joins the first data frame of `plu` with the first of `tsa` ... the last of `plu` with the last of `tsa`, and returns the results as a list.

```
> join_each = function(x, y) map2(x, y, full_join)
> join_each(query1$plu, query1$tsa)
Joining, by = c("id", "station")
Joining, by = c("id", "station")
Joining, by = c("id", "station")
$year
  id station  pluMean     pluMax     tsaMean    tsaMax
1  1     100 0.509069 0.01469622 -1.49060722 0.2573984
2  2     101 1.928665 0.80298439 -0.68473542 0.9576348
3  3     102 1.095175 2.48170762  0.05866559 1.3719802

$month
  id station    pluMean     pluMax    tsaMean     tsaMax
1  1     100  0.6649385  0.5034246 -0.6846687  0.9629169
2  2     101 -1.3559339  0.2344025 -1.2808785  0.5307734
3  3     102  0.1956006 -0.4402645 -0.6001755 -0.2171436

$week
  id station    pluMean    pluMax    tsaMean    tsaMax
1  1     100 -0.6082958 0.9696683  0.3764817 1.9383364
2  2     101 -1.1025692 0.9244263  0.3704359 0.8117675
3  3     102  1.7498401 3.4746087 -0.1053549 0.7449325
```

Well, this works when there are only two of them, but you want it to work when there are n lists of data.frames. Now you are going to need `purrr::reduce`:

```
> reduce(query1, join_each)
Joining, by = c("id", "station")
Joining, by = c("id", "station")
Joining, by = c("id", "station")
$year
  id station  pluMean     pluMax     tsaMean    tsaMax
1  1     100 0.509069 0.01469622 -1.49060722 0.2573984
2  2     101 1.928665 0.80298439 -0.68473542 0.9576348
3  3     102 1.095175 2.48170762  0.05866559 1.3719802

$month
  id station    pluMean     pluMax    tsaMean     tsaMax
1  1     100  0.6649385  0.5034246 -0.6846687  0.9629169
2  2     101 -1.3559339  0.2344025 -1.2808785  0.5307734
3  3     102  0.1956006 -0.4402645 -0.6001755 -0.2171436

$week
  id station    pluMean    pluMax    tsaMean    tsaMax
1  1     100 -0.6082958 0.9696683  0.3764817 1.9383364
2  2     101 -1.1025692 0.9244263  0.3704359 0.8117675
3  3     102  1.7498401 3.4746087 -0.1053549 0.7449325
```

It computes `join_each(query1[[1]], query1[[2]]) %>% join_each(query1[[3]]) ... %>% join_each(query1[[n]])`.

*Update*: The following one-liner does the same: `reduce(query1, map2, full_join)`. It isn't as readable, though.